# Prove that $3n6n3^2+4n8n4^2$ yields a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Let $n\geq 0$ be a nonnegative integer.

I observed that the expression $3n6n3^2+4n8n4^2$ is always a perfect square where $n$ represents number of "0". And I had verified it by using a calculator for at at most 7 digit composition of $3n6n3$ and $4n8n4$. That is:

$n=0:363^2+484^2=605^2$

$n=1:30603^2+40804^2=51005^2$

$n=2:3006003^2+4008004^2=5010005^2$

This computations put me on the affirmative side that in general as $n$ runs through positive integers the given sum always yields a perfect square.

But when im trying to prove it, I dont know where I will start.

Can someone help me prove that the expression $3n6n3^2+4n8n4^2$ always yields a perfect square? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Um, how do you get $363^2+484^2$ to be $605$? I get $366025$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, he forgot to put exponents on that side of the equations

Comment: @WillJagy: Ah, of course.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I get the square root of 366025 to get 605. Thanks ... and also to Will thanks.

Comment: @JrAntalan: You shouldn't write that 366025 is _equal to_ 605, though, because they are clearly not the same number.

Comment: Yeah, will edit the question now, you are right.

Comment: It's just a scaling of $\ 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2,\ $ see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In more usual notation, your observation is that whenever $b$ is a power of $10$, the number
$$ (3b^2+6b+3)^2 + (4b^2 + 8b + 4)^2 $$
is always a perfect square.

This holds even if $b$ is not a power of $10$. We have
$$ \begin{align} &(3b^2+6b+3)^2 + (4b^2 + 8b + 4)^2 \\
={}& (3(b^2+2b+1))^2 + (4(b^2+2b+1))^2 \\
={}& 9\cdot(b^2+2b+1)^2 + 16 \cdot (b^2+2b+1)^2 \\
={}& (9+16)\cdot (b^2+2b+1)^2 \\
={}& 25\cdot (b^2+2b+1)^2 \\
={}& (5(b^2+2b+1))^2 \end{align} $$

It also happens that $b^2+2b+1$ itself is a perfect square (namely of $b+1$), but that is not necessary for the rewriting to work.

Comment: Thanks Henning for giving me the general proof.

Answer (score 3):

$$  11^2 = 121  $$
$$ 101^2 = 10201  $$
$$ 1001^2 = 1002001  $$
$$ 10001^2 = 100020001  $$
and
$$ 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2 $$

Comment: Thanks Will, the proof is easier than I thought :-). Thanks again.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that $10\cdots020\cdots01$ is a perfect square, though -- the same property would hold with other coefficients than 1,2,1.

Comment: Now I knew it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you insert $n$ zeroes in the number $11$, this number is expressible as

$$N(n) = 10^{n+1}+1.$$

This number squared is

$$[N(n)]^2 = 10^{2n+2} + 2\cdot 10^{n+1} + 1.$$

By inspection, we see that the given expression is

$$3^2 [N(n)]^2 + 4^2 [N(n)]^2,$$

which equals $5^2 [N(n)]^2$.  As the product of two perfect squares this is itself a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks John for the Proof :-).

Answer (score 1):

We can represent those numbers like this:

$300....060....03 = 3 \cdot 10^{2n+2}+6 \cdot 10 ^{n+1} +3 $

$ 40....080...04 = 4 \cdot 10^{2n+2}+8 \cdot 10 ^{n+1} +4 $ where number of zeros between two numbers is n.

If we put $10^{n+1}=x $

we have  $3 \cdot 10^{2n+2}+6 \cdot 10 ^{n+1} +3 = 3x^2+6x+3 = 3(x+1)^2 $

and $4 \cdot 10^{2n+2}+8 \cdot 10 ^{n+1} +4 = 4x^2+8x+4 = 4(x+1)^2 $

Your sum of squares now looks like $[3(x+1)^2]^2+[4(x+1)]^2= 9(x+1)^4+16(x+1)^4=25(x+1)^4=[5(x+1)^2]^2$ which is a perfect square.

Comment: I see it nowzezanjee thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By $\,\rm\color{#c00}{DS} = $ Difference of Squares we see it's just a scaling of $\ \color{#0a0}{3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2}$

$\qquad\ (5x^2\!+\!10x\!+\!5)^2 - (4x^2\!+\!8x\!+\!4)^2 \overset{\rm\color{#c00}{DS}}= (9x^2\!+\!18x\!+\!9)(x^2\!+\!2x\!+\!1) = (3(x^2\!+\!2x\!+\!1))^2$

$\qquad  {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ \ (5(x+1)^2)^2 - (4(x+1)^2)^2 \overset{\rm\color{#c00}{DS}}= 9(x+1)^2\,(x+1)^2 = (3(x+1)^2)^2\qquad\qquad\quad\ $

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ \    (5X)^2 - (4X)^2 \overset{\rm\color{#c00}{DS}}= (9X) X\, =\, (3X)^2$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\      (\color{#0a0}{5^2 - 4^2} \overset{\rm\color{#c00}{DS}}=\, \color{#0a0}{3^2})\,X^2$

Comment: Thanks Bill, yeah in deed it was just a scaling... thanks again.